# Is there a way to automate adding a numeric value into a DF in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like

| team | name |
| --- | --- |
| San Francisco Giants | Tommy La Stella |
| San Francisco Giants | Mike Yastrzemski |
| San Francisco Giants | Wilmer Flores |
| San Francisco Giants | Joc Pederson |
| San Francisco Giants | Brandon Crawford |
| San Francisco Giants | Curt Casali |
| San Francisco Giants | Luis Gonzalez |
| San Francisco Giants | Donovan Walton |
| San Francisco Giants | Jason Vosler |

I'd like to add a third column with a projected amount of plate appearances, I have the number in a separate value for this example it's 23.60.
So I'd like the third column to look something like

| proj.pa |
| --- |
| 3 |
| 3 |
| 3 |
| 3 |
| 3 |
| 2.6 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 2 |

I can easily add the column manually using a vector like
c(3,3,3,3,3,2.6,2,2,2)
but I was wondering if there is a way to automate that, so I only have to supply the total number.

I've played around with loops and the trunc function, but I'm just not having any luck figuring out a possible solution.

Comment: Show us also this additional object, where you have these values.

Comment: It's just a numeric value that I'm pulling from a different data frame, so its just proj.pa <- 23.6

Comment: Then this does not add up, you say it's just an additional number 23.6, however the vector you show in your desired output is not equal to this. So which is it?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean that you want a vector that is randomly generated of a certain length with a predetermined sum.

For the example you have shown, you could do something a bit hacky like this

```r
while(sum(x <- sample(c(2, 2.6, 3), size = 9, replace = T)) != 23.6){}
x
#> [1] 3.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 3.0 2.6 2.0 2.0 3.0
```

Which is not deterministic, rather, it keeps generating samples until a solution presents itself. The loop will continue forever if a solution does not exist, so I suggest re-evaluating the task you are trying to fulfill.

Comment: Okay, so I'm taking a different approach and have sequenced the first data frame 3 times, giving me 27 rows. Is there a way to create a function that would create a column like 
#> [1] 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.6 0.0 0.0 0.0
Then I could just groupby summarize

Comment: You could alter the vector to sample from a different vector, change the size, and sort the resulting vector. Note, however that there are multiple solutions: `[1] 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.0`. The problem needs to be more well defined.